# Volume control with the Deezer Android SDK

Tags: android, deezer

Does the SDK provide any way to control the volume of the Deezer SDK's internal AudioTrack instance, or is there another way this could be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now there is no control at all on the internal AudioTrack's volumne but we'll try and add this feature in a future release of the SDK